# Set dropdown text after Li click of dinamically added items

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, dropdown, bootstrap-5

Bootstrap 5. This is my code, just the UL since once the page is loaded the list of `<li>` come dinamically from a database.

```
 <div class="btn-group">
      <button id="dropdownGerencia" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        My list
      </button>
      <ul id="mtUl" class="dropdown-menu">

      </ul>
```

Now, once the list is populated, I want my dropdown to show the selected value by the user. I have this code. But the problem is that my dropdown is nested with other dropdowns (with a single `.btn-group` above them all. So when they click on one particular LI all the dropdowns (because of  `.btn-group` get the value, instead of only the one where the li exists.

```
 $(".dropdown-menu").on('click', ' li a', function () {
        var selText = $(this).text();
        $(this).parents('.btn-group').find('.dropdown-toggle').html(selText + '  ' + '<span class="caret"></span>');

    });
```

I also tried this but this doesnt show the selected value since it was created dinamically afterwards.

```
 $('#myUl li').on('click', function () {
        $('#mySpecificDropdown').html($(this).find('a').html());
    });
```

Comment: How do *you* know which `select` it should be?   All you've told is "my dropdown" .. "my dropdown is nested with other dropdowns".   Give the tiny snippet of code that only shows one dropdown, I would hazard a guess at `$(this).prev().html(selText...`

Comment: *since it was created dynamically* -> use event delegation:  `$('#myUl li').on('click', function...` -> `$(document).on("click", "#myUI li", function..`   However, this will be a bad choice as you'll need the same code for every `li`/`a` pair.   Can you change the HTML *at all*?  If so, please provide a longer snippet that *demonstrates* the issue. See [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You can sue [prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) to the previous element to the selected element and using same change the text of your button or get the index of the current `dropdown-menu` and use that to select needed `dropdown-menu`.

***Demo Code:***

```js
$(".dropdown-menu").on('click', ' li a', function() {
  var selText = $(this).text();
  var index_ = $('.dropdown-menu').index($(this).closest('.dropdown-menu'));

  $(this).closest('.dropdown-menu').prev().html(selText + '  ' + '<span class="caret"></span>');

  //or use below with index

  // $('.dropdown-toggle').eq(index_).html(selText + '  ' + '<span class="caret"></span>')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="btn-group">
  <button id="dropdownGerencia" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown link
  </button>

  <ul id="mtUl" class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else</a></li>
  </ul>

  <button id="dropdownGerencia1" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown link
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```